# Concatenating Two Pandas DataFrames with the same length extends the length of the resulting DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-3.5

I have two DataFrames that I am trying to concat together.  df_output_norm is the dataframe I am trying to get.  X_test_minmax has 81732 rows and 6 columns, y_test has 81732 rows and 1 column.  This should be an easy concatenation, but when I concatenate it, the resulting size is (147158, 7)

```
df_output_norm = pd.DataFrame()
df_output_norm = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_test_minmax), pd.DataFrame(y_test)], axis=1)

print(df_output_norm.shape)
print(df_output_norm['label'].shape)
print(X_test_minmax.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
```

The output is
(147158, 7)
(147158,)
(81732, 6)
(81732,)

The number of columns is correct, just that the number of rows in the last column is wrong.  I've looked at the data and only the last column 'label' is extended, which is the column y_test.  The first 6 columns that come from X_test_minmax are of the correct row length.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty old question, but I landed here looking for a solution to the same problem. I figured out that its because of the mismatch in row indices as the function will be trying to concat on them (very likely that you have chunked your dfs from a larger one by sampling or so).

Try

X_test_minmax.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True) 
y_test.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True) 
df_output_norm = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_test_minmax), pd.DataFrame(y_test)], axis=1)

Answer (score 0):

If ignore_index =True is not working, this is possibly caused by the duplicated column names: One of the column name in the first dataframe is the same as the column name of the second dataframe. Change the column name might help.

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps the index is preventing the result you are seeking. Try

```
f_output_norm = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(X_test_minmax), pd.DataFrame(y_test)],
                          axis=1, 
                          ignore_index=True)
```

to ignore indexes on the concatenation axis.

Comment: This didn't work, do you have any other suggestions?  I've looked through the docs and this is a really weird error that no one seems to have encountered before

Comment: can you replicate the result with toy DFs that you manufacture? Try to create two DFs, with 4 rows and same number of cols, and test that.... If you can replicate that, edit your question with those DFs so that we can try.